# jquery next by class fade out

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div id="formheadtop">
 <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" /></div><div class="formbody"></div>
<div id="formheadtop">
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" /></div><div class="formbody"></div>
<div id="formheadtop"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" /></div><div class="formbody"></div>



$(function() { $('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
if ( $(this).attr('checked') == true ) 
{
    $(this).nextAll('.formbody:first').fadeIn();
}
else
{ 
$('.formbody').fadeOut();
};
});
```

The Code doesn't work. I want to fade out only the next div.formbody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we'll need to change `id="formheadtop"` to `class="formheadtop"`, since `ID`s must be unique. Then you can use this code to fade in and out the `DIV`s:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.formheadtop :checkbox').live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).parent().next('.formbody').fadeIn();
    }  else { 
      $(this).parent().next('.formbody').fadeOut();
    };
  });
});
```

You could shorten `$(this).parent().next('.formbody')` to `$(this).parent().next().fadeIn()`, but I put in the selector, just in case you ever want to put something in between.

**HTML**

```
<div class="formheadtop"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></div>
<div class="formbody">test</div>
<div class="formheadtop"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></div>
<div class="formbody">test</div>
<div class="formheadtop"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></div>
<div class="formbody">test</div>
```

I made the checkboxes *checked* by default. If not, you'll need to hide the content in the `formbody` tags.

Here's the [code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/n5GFX/).

Comment: Impressive answer - looks like a lot of work went into that, with code sample in action and all. Nice job!

Comment: Thanks. It didn't take that much time. Hopefully it will be useful. :)